# How to handle comments pointing to no longer existing chat

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

Today I found a question where there were some conversation in the comments between the OP and another user. After a few of these comments, the OP decided that further discussion should take place in chat and added a comment with a link to a chat.

Since I found their conversation interesting I wanted to follow it in the chat. When I clicked the link I found that the chat was no longer available. That's why I flagged that comment as "no longer needed". But my flag got declined.

Should I have flagged it for moderator attention instead?

Comment: Can you link to the particular comment?

Comment: @StephenLeppik it's the last comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52125602)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use "other" and say "chat room was deleted". Moderators typically process comment flags very quickly, and since the link is the only thread connecting the two, the only reason a mod would remove it is if the chat was deleted.

The mod could then undelete the chat if they wanted to, or just delete the link, but "no longer needed" would probably make a mod say *no, that is needed, we keep those comments around* unless they knew the comment was now pointless because the conversation was gone :)

I could have *sworn* that we once made removing that link automatic if a chat room was deleted, but I can't find reference to it.

Comment: You could probably quote one of [these comments](/q/320761/6388243), as I was going to on my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree. For 10K-ers that room is still visible. Wouldn't it be their call if the comment really served their goal and can be deleted. I don't expect a mod will visit that chat room to figure out if the knowledge exchange is relevant and captured in an edit/post on the Q/A.

Comment: Well, a deleted room is still a 404 (similar to how a deleted question is a 404 that also renders the question if you have privileges to view it). To _most_ people (including search engines), it's just a broken link. Now I'm getting curious as to how often this is actually happening.